# validating string with wildcards or placeholders for up to 2 missing chars

Tags: c#, regex, validation, t-sql

I'm working on a business layer query to validate an entry against a list of valid entries in a database.  I am trying to validate with up to 2 wild card placeholders.  For example, XXXX_XX, with _ being the wildcard.  To validate the instance where there is only a single _ I'm using the following code:

```
if (DiagCode.Contains("_"))
                {
                    int count=0;
                    foreach (char c in DiagCode)
                    {                           
                        if(c.ToString() =="_")
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        int loc = DiagCode.IndexOf("_");
                        int len = DiagCode.Length;
                        int end = len - loc;

                        string diagCodeSubBegin = DiagCode.Substring(0, loc);
                        string diagCodeSubEnd = DiagCode.Substring(loc, end);

                        NHCSLINQ.MODEL.DIAGS_ICD10 tblDIAG_ICD102 = (from c in NHCSDB.DIAGS_ICD10s
                                                                     where c.Code.StartsWith(diagCodeSubBegin)
                                                                     && c.Code.EndsWith(diagCodeSubEnd)
                                                                     select c).SingleOrDefault();
                        if (tblDIAG_ICD102 != null)
                        {

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
```

The problem arises when I have an entry as such, XX_XX_X.  I've thought about using Regex to split the code an validate each piece individually as seen below.

```
if (count ==2)
                    {

                        string[] lines = Regex.Split(DiagCode, "_");

                        foreach (string line in lines)
                        {
                            int loc = DiagCode.IndexOf("_");
                            int len = DiagCode.Length;
                            int end = len - loc;
                            string diagCodeSubBegin = DiagCode.Substring(0, loc);
                            string diagCodeSubEnd = DiagCode.Substring(loc, end);

                            NHCSLINQ.MODEL.DIAGS_ICD10 tblDIAG_ICD102 = (from c in NHCSDB.DIAGS_ICD10s
                                                                         where c.Code.StartsWith(diagCodeSubBegin)
                                                                         && c.Code.EndsWith(diagCodeSubEnd)
                                                                         select c).SingleOrDefault();
                            if (tblDIAG_ICD102 != null)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

But then I'm at a loss to reconnect the individual strings as a whole with the _ in place.  There must be an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is rather unclear what you are doing. `_` with `LIKE` means 1 character, and you make it work as `%` pattern (0 or more characters), right?

Comment: Not clear what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to validate a string that can be missing up to 2 characters against a the database.  For example, XXXXXXX is a direct match.  XXX_XXX should also be a match, which I am able to do, What I'm struggling to figure out is the XX_X_XX style.  Think of it like a lock on a briefcase with the rotating numbers.  I need it to unlock regardless of what is in the place of the _.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?
TSQL [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) has that and ironically they use _.